# sending e-mail from Rails Web app without using smtp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I just try to send an e-mail to signed up user from my rails web app. Do I need to use any smtp server or can I just send a mail from my app.? Do you have any suggestion idea about this? Thanks for returns :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need an SMTP server for sending mail.

There are two options, first is to use  a mail server provided by someone else, e.g. the SMTP of the company that provides your server or their ISP.

The other option is to install a MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) on your server, one popular options is [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/). See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix) for instructions for Ubunutu.